# sql count date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, база-данных

Есть запрос

```
SELECT calldate,count(*) FROM cdr WHERE dstchannel LIKE '%6392%' AND type = 'main' AND direction= 'incoming' AND calldate between '2015-06-01' and '2015-08-31' group by calldate;
```

Результат:

```
      calldate        | count 
------------------------+-------
 2015-06-02 09:31:07+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 09:48:12+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 10:12:15+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 10:21:12+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 10:37:20+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 11:51:08+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 12:12:06+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 12:16:36+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 12:50:24+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 13:10:07+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 13:17:20+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 14:21:12+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 15:13:12+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 15:18:03+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 15:21:45+03 |     1
 2015-06-02 15:52:36+03 |     1
 2015-06-03 15:06:36+03 |     1
```

Желаемый результат:

```
 calldate        | count 
------------------------+-------
 2015-06-02  |     16
 2015-06-03  |     1
```

поле calldate имеет вид `2015-06-03 15:06:36+03`

Подскажите как отредактировать запрос что бы получить желаемый результат ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна группировка по полю `calldate`,  но только по дате, без временной части...
MySQL функция `DATE()` берет только дату из поля типа `datetime` - вот по ней и группируйте.

Вот такой вариант:

```
SELECT DATE(calldate) as calldate, count(*) 
FROM cdr 
WHERE dstchannel LIKE '%6392%' AND type = 'main' AND direction= 'incoming' 
    AND calldate between '2015-06-01' and '2015-08-31' 
GROUP BY DATE(calldate);
```